# Click Button and Count Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I want to Count how many times I click a button and display the number, but the format should be like: 0001 if reach 9999 restart to 0001 again and count till 9999.

I tried:

```
Private ButtonClickCount As Integer = 0
ButtonClickCount += 1
Label5.Text = "0000" & ButtonClickCount
```

And

```
Label5.Text = "0000" + Val(Label5.Text) + 1
```

This was the dumbest way I tried.lol

And the result was disapointing.

Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Call `ToString` on the number and you can format it however you like. Read the documentation to find out what options are available.

Comment: As for the other part, read what you wrote: "if reach 9999 restart to 0001 again". That's basically pseudocode already so how about you put in the little bit of thought required to turn it into actual code. When you say "if" in your description, it should be fairly obvious that you need an `If` statement in your code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks. Will do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a [Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static) variable for the count, you can keep it in the button click event handler. (Static variables aren't used all that often, but it works here, assuming you don't need the variable anywhere else.)

If you check if the counter has reached 10000, you can set it back to 1.

You can format the number in the .ToString method.

Perhaps something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static clickCount As Integer = 0
    clickCount += 1
    If clickCount = 10000 Then
        clickCount = 1
    End If
    lblClickCount.Text = clickCount.ToString("0000")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Format command, which controls how many zeroes you want in the output:

```
    Dim ButtonClicks As Integer = 0
    
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ButtonClicks += 1
        Label1.Text = Format(ButtonClicks, "0000")
    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ButtonClicks As Integer = 0

Private sub Button1_click(sender as object, e as EventArgs) handles Button 1.click

    Buttonclick +=1

    If buttonclick ="9999" then

        Buttonlclick=1

    Endif

    Label1.text =format(Buttonclick, "0000")
End sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to keep track of the counter **somewhere**, in this case I would suggest storing the counter in the control's Tag property ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag)). In your button's click event, you would do the following:

1. Get the Tag
2. Convert the value to an Integer
3. Increment the value by 1
4. Check if the new value is greater than 9999
5. Optionally reset the value to 1 if 4 is true
6. Set the Text of the Button to the formatted result
7. Set the Tag of the button to the new value

Here is an example:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim clickedButton = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim tagValue = clickedButton.Tag
    If (tagValue Is Nothing) Then
        tagValue = 0
    End If

    Dim conversion As Integer
    If (Not Integer.TryParse(tagValue.ToString(), conversion)) Then
        conversion = 0
    End If

    conversion += 1
    If (conversion > 9999) Then
        conversion = 1
    End If

    clickedButton.Text = converstion.ToString("0000")
    clickedButton.Tag = conversion
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, sorry guys, just realized that I could use the PadLeft function... And worked fine.

```
    ButtonClickCount += 1
    Label5.Text = ButtonClickCount.ToString().PadLeft(5, "0")
```

But Still don't know if it reaches 9999 will restart from 0001

Comment: Test it: `Private ButtonClickCount As Integer = 9990`

Comment: Nope, that's not it.